# generate random parameter value for a method without knowing the parameter type

Tags: c#

What problem do I want to solve? Via reflection I want to execute code (running instance methods and also static methods) where I dont know beforehand how the method to be run is defined.

Lets say I have a `MethodInfo` that I want to invoke. I have no idea what parameters it has, so I do following.

first I check that method params are valid (if not valid then method is not invoked):

```
 private static IEnumerable<Type> GetValidMethodTypes()
    {
        var validTypes = new List<Type>();
        validTypes.AddRange(new[]
        {
            typeof (SByte),
            typeof(String[]),
            //etc...
        });

        return validTypes;
    }
```

Then I generate random values based on param type:

```
 public object RandomizeParamValue(string typeName)
    {
        switch (typeName)
        {
            case "SByte":
            {
                //return randomized value
            }
            case "String[]":
            {
                //return randomized value
            }
            //etc...
        }
     }
```

for example, a randomized value for String[] would be ["a","ab", "ccc"] or ["aa", "b"]. The formula is: new string[random size between 1 and 5 ] that contains random strings with random lengths. Everything super random :)

The problem is that this works only with what types I support in my code. I could offcourse add support for many many more types but it is much work. I would like to make this much more generic but I dont really know how. I have googled this but found nothing. Anyone knows of a solution/known pattern for this kind of problem?

I can re-formulate the question like this: How can I, via reflection, invoke following method:

```
void SomeMethod(unknowntypeatcompiletime param);
```

where unknowntypeatcompiletime could be anything.

Comment: How could you do something generic? What can be inherently common between a random number and a random Car object? The rules about this can't be generic, so I think you have to implement each type separately.

Comment: what should be a randomized value for String[] for example ? do you mean default value or a random array like `new [] { "foo", "bar"} ; ` or an empty array?

Comment: *Or some open source lib that does something similar* Remove this from your question, else it is likely to be closed with reason `Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow`

Comment: Why do you need this? What are you trying to achieve with it?

Comment: @Kilazur What could be inherently common is that they're comprised of primitive types. Couldn't OP recursively drill into objects via reflection and randomize all primitive types until they're all set?

Comment: @xdumaine In that case, yes. But once more, it would be (arguably) cleaner (and easier to maintain/modify), since he actually knows what types can be used, to implement (extension) method by type. Generic methods are meant to be generic, this one is specific to some types.

Comment: @xdumaine no, I dont know what types can be used and I want to support any type. Even generics. I want to randomize for example an instance of List<List<<uint>>

Comment: @balinikas my suggestion doesn't require you to know the types, and would work with genetics.

Comment: @xdumaine I am not sure I understand, can you ellaborate, or give an example?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to have a randomizer which will work for any possible type.

Depending on what you want to achieve, you might find some of the Mock and TDD frameworks, such as Moq or AutoFixture, useful (latter one can create objects with random data). They create however mocked objects, and it is an open question to what level they can do randomizing.

Another way is to have some sort of values seed in a file outside of your application. That seed file can contain object graphs of the possible types, of which one is randomly chosen. The file can be loaded at runtime and thus would not require recompiling. This solution would however require you to extend seed as soon you want to support new types.

Answer (score 0):

It is really impossible to support types that you do not know prior to run-time.

However, it is quite easy to provide a dynamic way of adding types.

Try something like this:

```
public class Randomizer
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _randoms
        = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public void Add<T>(Func<T> generate)
    {
        _randoms.Add(typeof(T), generate);
    }

    public T RandomizeParamValue<T>()
    {
        return ((Func<T>)_randoms[typeof(T)])();
    }
}
```

You can then add the random delegates quite easily like this:

```
var rz = new Randomizer();
var rnd = new Random();
rz.Add(() => rnd.Next());
rz.Add(() => new [] { "a", "b", "c" }.ElementAt(rnd.Next(0, 3)));
```

Now I can easily call this code to get the random values:

```
var randIntegers = rz.RandomizeParamValue<int>();
var randStrings = rz.RandomizeParamValue<string>();
```

Very easy. Let me know if this helps.